# Why is Inkscape creating a diamond-shaped hole when I fill in my path?

Tags: inkscape, path, fill

I created the outline of the bee shape below using the arc tool for the head and body, and the Bezier curve Spiro path tool for the side wings. I then connected these 4 paths using Combine paths (CTRL-K).
[image: bee shape] [image: filled in bee shape with diamond in middle]

Now when I try to fill in this path I get this empty diamond in the middle where it won't fill in, shown below the bee shape.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Combining paths doesn't join separate paths. It only creates a compound path which is not what you want. Instead, you would need to select and join (Shift+J) the connecting nodes to make a single closed path.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to select the nodes of the individual lobes and use the join selected node button in order to get a complete fill. Use F2 to enter node editing, click on one path, shift click on second path adjoining, then draw a bounding box over the common nodes. Using the join selected node button will create a single node where there was previously two. After a minimum number of joining the nodes, the fill will be complete.